# Getting an error during yarn build in React JS

Tags: reactjs, build, node-modules, react-scripts

Build of my project is failing - it is throwing the below mentioned error.

**React version - 17.0.2**

**react-scripts - 4.0.3**

app-frontend\App>yarn build
yarn run v1.22.17
$ react-app-rewired build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/tempa-xlsx/node_modules/pako/lib/zlib/trees.js 237:106
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (237:106)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  |  *     not null.
  |  */

> function gen_bitlen(s, desc) /*    deflate_state *s;*/ /*    tree_desc *desc;    /* the tree descriptor */*/{
> |   var tree = desc.dyn_tree;
> |   var max_code = desc.max_code;

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I've tried by upgrading react-scripts from 3.44 to 4.0.3

I've removed the node_modules and re-ran the yarn install and yarn build again.

Comment: similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/74323826/7665352

Comment: that didn't work.

Comment: [#262](https://github.com/nodeca/pako/issues/262) issue is resolved in recent version of pako, released with the fix [2.1.0](https://github.com/nodeca/pako/releases/tag/2.1.0) Changelog : https://github.com/nodeca/pako/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#210---2022-11-07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add : above mentioned babel libraries (thatGuyDaki) in resolutions section instead of depedencies in package.json. so that it does not install any further updates of babel libraries, usually whenever your yarn-lock.json/package-lock.json files deleted, then more upto date babel version gets pulled In. that's why you are getting an error.

By adding babel libraries in resolutions : resolutions is simply a map of package names and the exact versions of those packages that should be kept in the dependency tree and also it will remove previous versions.

```
 resolutions : {
"@babel/core": "7.19.6",
"@babel/generator": "7.19.6",
"@babel/compat-data": "7.19.4",
"@babel/helper-compilation-targets": "7.19.3",
"@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin": "7.19.0",
"@babel/helper-module-transforms": "7.19.6"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same problem. I had to downgrade some @Babel libraries. Found the solution [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74323826/module-parse-failed-unexpected-token-257106-you-may-need-an-appropriate-load).
Basically, add this to the dependencies in your package.json:

```
"@babel/core": "7.19.6",
"@babel/generator": "7.19.6",
"@babel/compat-data": "7.19.4",
"@babel/helper-compilation-targets": "7.19.3",
"@babel/helper-create-class-features-plugin": "7.19.0",
"@babel/helper-module-transforms": "7.19.6",
```

Then run npm install again.

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work. Getting the same issue

Comment: I had to just put the above libraries in resolutions, not in dependencies, thanks @thatGuyDaki